# robot framework: difference in encoding between old formatting %s and new formatting

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, robotframework

1. I have a library with keyword. Keyword write some message to a test documentation.
2. This python file in `utf-8`, and has needed heading 
   `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
3. `*.robot` files are in `utf-8`

Execution of this keyword in robot file with non-ascii symbols gives:

1. If keyword has `"%s" % msg`: no error, log file gives russian message, normally displayed.
2. If keyword has `"{}".format(msg)` or `"{!s}".format(msg)`: I get the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)`

As you can see, I change only old python formatting to the new way. But how to fix this problem sith non-asc displaying error with new way, not using old style formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Str.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_decode.htm) method. See [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode).

Example:

```
"{}".format(msg.decode(errors='replace'))
```

Comment: Not works. 1. I cannot 'replace' any things because all russian text will be removed then and the reason of it is 2. The problem is that somehow the string `"{}"` have `ascii` encoding. Thats why `msg` which is unicode russian string cannot be converted into `ascii`. I've RTFM and I know that header of py file should work (i've set this header as `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`) but strings in this file are still in `ascii`. I can solve this problem if I explicitly define constant strings as unicode writing them as `u"some string"` and after that I won't get any error. But why header isn't working?